# From QGIS 3.4.5 and 3.6 asks password repeadly to connect to PostgreSQL 10

Tags: qgis, postgresql, connection, password

Action: At first time when opening project on QGIS 3.4.5 and 3.6 versions needs credentials to connect to PostgreSQL DB.

Problem: But after that when connection is success with correct credentials the qgis repeatedly asks the same credentials again to connect to the same DB when the maps is zooming and moving and etc.

[image: repeatedly shows this window]

With QGIS 2.18, 3.4.0, 3.4.1 versions all works fine and don't asking repeatedly credentials after first correct time.

Maybe someone knows whats is wrong?

Comment: Just a link to the bug report: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21582

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the password during PostgreSQL connection adding. 
Once you did it. QGIS should not ask you again for the password. However, for single password insert it sounds like a bug in QGIS but without proper investigation is hard to say. Multiple reasons can cause this behavior that you're connection is trying to refresh.

[image: Password storing]

Comment: If you think it's a bug, please report it on the [proper site](https://issues.qgis.org) (GIS SE is *not* a bug reporting site).

Comment: Thank You, Vince, but that I had done before, but problem still was there.

Comment: @gcalibris - I'm here because I'm having the same issue. Can you share the bug report you filed, so I can track its progress?

Comment: @J.Taylor -  try to install qgis 3.4.7 version, http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/win64/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.4.7-1-Setup-x86_64.exe. This version is working fine, without this issue. This version of qgis http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/win64/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.6.2-1-Setup-x86_64.exe I haven't tested yet, but perhaps with this version is fine also.

Comment: Has a solution been found yet to this question perhaps? I have the same issue. I am using QGIS 3.6