# Store Login Data in QGIS Project

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have a QGIS project with data from a postgresql database. For this database you need a login. 
If I open the QGIS project I have to enter the login data.

Is there any possibility to store the login data for my database in the project?

I tried to save my project as a .qgs file and store the logindata in this file. But I still have to enter my login data if I open my project.

[image]

Comment: Yes you can save logins in the project. Please refer to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/335580/postgresql-password-setup-in-qgis-disallowing-multiple-authentication-to-indivi/335646#335646

Comment: The project should be used by ohters and for them I want to store the login data. Is it with your solution possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, once you save the password, they do not have to re-enter it.