# How can I keep a QGIS connection as simple as psql?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, direct-connect

In a terminal I do all, with all permissions by this **simple** command and no extra credentials:

```sh
psql postgres://postgres@localhost/myDB  # No password!! No other credentials!
```

That is: host=localhost, user=postgres, database=myDB.

So, how can I **keep QGIS simple** to connect with my local PostgreSQL instance?

Can I connect to QGIS using only it? Only host/user/database.

---

### NOTES

- I suppose that QGIS's community is mature (since 2002), and it needs and pushes for [easy to use and simplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)...
- I suppose that [QGIS was created to be used with PostGIS](https://www.xyht.com/spatial-itgis/godfather-of-qgis/)... So I suppose that what I need is valid for all versions... But, if you need a reference, I am using QGIS v3+ with PostgreSQL v12+, `psql` version 12+ and PostGIS 3+.
- Please, any simple solution, by terminal **or** by menu "Add Layer/PostgreSQL", with no password and no extra-credentials.  [This question/answer use password](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314735/7505), so it is not a solution.

Comment: You shouldn't ever connect to a PostgreSQL database as `postgres` via QGIS. The admin login exists to allow you to create less privileged login roles and group roles for the actual security model that will be used for your project.  Passwords are a way to prevent unauthorized access. `psql` stores passwords in a dotfile (in clear text!) to permit casual access. This is nearly enough to get PG banished from sites that take security seriously. pgAdmin4 addressed this with encypherment of the connection passwords. It seems this enhancement request is going is the other direction.

Comment: No @Vince, the question is not  about env configuration, is about "how to do the same", in an environment where I am happy, no changes, no need for password.

Comment: Do you fully understand WHY your commandline works? How the authentication process of PostgreSQL works and why peer authentication is a thing?

Why do you believe that giving a username/password ONCE (when setting up the connection) is not "simple"?

Your question needs more details to get a good answer.

Comment: Hi @Tom, you and Vince are making a big mistake... Again, it **is not** an online server exposed to attacks from all internet, it is my personal desktop machine, on my house, and conecting database by *localhost*. So **the authentication process is the *login* on my Linux machine**. I use internet-banking, etc. I have local family photos, etc. so **it is reliable** for me and **my personal PostgreSQL use**.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Postgres has its own authentication process. Unless you set up peer authentication, your login does **not** automatically transfer to Postgres. I do a lot of dev work involving Postgres, and I've consistently found that user/pass with roles specified in the DB is more reliable than peer auth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you declared the database once like in screen capture and clicked OK, it's over. And yes, I don't use a password and it works out of the box (click on "Test Connection" if you doubt) Already too complex? You can't avoid declaring the connexion before using it. You may use pg_service.conf file approach (cf https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-pgservice.html) otherwise and fill only the "Service" in the same panel as below screen capture.

[image]